# Infinite Loop when using foreach C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach, ms-word, add-in

I'm making a word Add-in using c# and visual studio 2010.

I did a simple test code to accept all document revisions as follows:

```
if (CurrentDocument.Revisions.Count > 0)
{
    Project.LoadingWindow.LoadingWindow loadingWindow = 
                new LoadingWindow.LoadingWindow("Updating...");
    loadingWindow.ProgressBarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher loadingWindowDispatcher = 
                loadingWindow.Dispatcher;

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
    worker.DoWork += delegate
    {
        List<Revision> revisions = new List<Revision>();
        int count = 0;
        foreach (Revision rev in CurrentDocument.Revisions)
        {
             count++;
             revisions.Add(rev);
        }
        AcceptRevisions(revisions, loadingWindowDispatcher, loadingWindow);

        worker.Dispose();
        worker = null;
     };

     worker.RunWorkerAsync();
     loadingWindow.Show();
}
```

If I put a breakpoint after the foreach, the debug won't reach.

CurrentDocument.Revisions.Count is **618**

But using a int counter, I can see that the count reaches easily **9000!**

What I'am doing wrong? I'm a little new to Visual Studio and C#, but I can't seem to figure out what is possibly going on.

Comment: Sorry to say, but that is not possible. `foreach` is deterministic.

Comment: Sorry, added the counter.

Comment: This is done under a delegate for a Background worker. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: Are you making in recursive call?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: if the collection you are enumerating is modified while you're enumerating, all bets are off. If that is the case here we can't tell from the code, but I have seen `foreach` loops that didn't terminate.

Comment: An enumerator fails when the collection changes

Comment: @JeroenMostert, a `foreach` is being used which means `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` would be thrown.

Comment: Show us more code.  Specifically how you are starting the BackgroundWorker, the DoWork() handler, and firing off the delegate.  Under what conditions do you start the BackgroundWorker()?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman, @Idle_Mind: this works if and only if the collection has actually implemented logic to detect this, and even then it only works in specific cases. For example, `List<T>` will reliably detect modifications from a single thread because it maintains a version counter, but this doesn't necessarily work if you're modifying the same instance from multiple threads.

Comment: I added the full code.

Answer (score 1):

**I'm a complete Word Interop NOOB here.**  Had to download and install the Office Templates for VS so I could play with this.  I also don't work with WPF so I substituted in a plain WinForms Form with a BackgroundWorker and a Label on it.

Why aren't you working with `Application.ActiveDocument.Revisions` directly?

I added a Button to my Word Document and populated a List, then passed that to a Form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Application.ActiveDocument.Revisions.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Revision> revisions = new List<Revision>();
            foreach (Revision rev in Application.ActiveDocument.Revisions)
            {
                revisions.Add(rev);
            }

            frmAcceptRevisions accept = new frmAcceptRevisions(revisions);
            accept.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Here's frmAcceptRevisions:

```
public partial class frmAcceptRevisions : Form
{

    private List<Revision> _Revisions = null;

    public frmAcceptRevisions(List<Revision> Revisions)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._Revisions = Revisions;
        this.Shown += frmAcceptRevisions_Shown;
    }

    private void frmAcceptRevisions_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _Revisions.Count; i++)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i + 1);
            _Revisions[i].Accept();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // for illustrative purposes only
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Applying Revision " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " of " + _Revisions.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Revisions Accepted: " + _Revisions.Count.ToString());
        this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }

}
```

I then ran the project, typed some text into my document, turned on Track Changes, and made a bunch of modifications.  When I clicked the Button my Form popped up and I could see each Revision being accepted and changed in the document with my form updating with progress as expected (because of the long delay I hard-coded in the loop).

Comment: Out of curiosity, which part was helpful here?  The `Application.ActiveDocument.Revisions` bit, or the Forms part?...or a little of both?

Comment: Actually, it was the idea of using a "for i" instead of a foreach. Because that worked oddly enough.